# can someone tell me what's wrong with my program using fork() system calls(Programming C)

Tags: c, linux, excel, unix, fork

In this program, I am trying to use fork() functions to create 6 child processes and execute executionnode() functions,but I feel there is something wrong in my output! 
what happened to my code or system calls?
I have a program like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>



int executionnode(int i);

int main(){
pid_t childpid;
     int i;
     int row=6;
     for(i=0;i<row;i++)
     {   childpid=fork();
         if(childpid==0)
            continue;
         else if (childpid>0)
            executionnode(i);

         else {
           perror("something wrong");
            exit(1);
          }
      }


}


int executionnode(int i){
   sleep(i);
   printf("hello, I am process:%ld\n",(long)getpid());
   char *execArgs[] = { "echo", "Hello, World!", NULL };
   execvp("echo", execArgs);

}
```

Everytime when I run this program,the output is always like this in my Linux terminal:

```
/*
hello, I am process:3226
Hello, World!
lixx3527@tiandiao123:~/Desktop/pa1-release$ hello, I am process:3227
Hello, World!
hello, I am process:3228
Hello, World!
hello, I am process:3229
Hello, World!
hello, I am process:3230
Hello, World!
hello, I am process:3231
Hello, World!
*/
```

I find my output even didn't finish, which means my program's executions haven't been finished, but `lixx3527@tiandiao123:~/Desktop/pa1-release$` has appeared in the terminal ahead of time.
 what happened to my code or system calls?
can someone help me explain it? I mean why `lixx3527@tiandiao123:~/Desktop/pa1-release$` appeared before the program finished its all the execution?
 thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Waiting for execvp in main](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3637973/waiting-for-execvp-in-main)

Answer (score 3):

The parent runs very quickly, forking children.  Then it quits and the shell prints a prompt.  Then the other children run and print data.  It looks like one child is able to print before the shell prints a prompt, and the others don't.  If you want the parent to wait for the children to finish, there is a function conveniently named `wait` that will do that.

Comment: It should be noted that `wait` will only free a single zombie child process. In order for all child processes to finish first, look at `waitpid` and use it for each child process created.